# For loops range in Python

Tags: python, loops

In case of FOR LOOPS,
when we write a range as shown in the following code:

```
a=[]
for i in range(1,35):
    if i%7==0:
        a.append(i)
print(a)
```

why doesn't it include the last value.

But in the following code:

```
for i in range(1,18):
    if row[i]=='A':
        print(row)
```

It includes the last value which is 18 as well.
(The second code is  used on a csv file)

Please someone help.

Comment: You're mistaken. There is no difference in endpoint handling between the two snippets you've posted.

Comment: The second code does NOT include 18.

Comment: @Jacobm001: 35%7 does equal 0.

Comment: ``range`` never includes the last value. It is a half-open interval, just like the indices of a sequence are a half-open interval of [0, len(seq)).

Comment: The range of Python's `range` is inclusive on the left bound and exclusive on the right bound. Just include `print(i)` in the for loop definition to see for yourself. Unfortunately, you haven't provided enough information to reproduce your second example.

Comment: `%` is used to check for reminders. Since 35 is not included in the `range` as others mentioned in the comment, thus 35 will not be printed as the output.

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those will include the last value, if by last value you mean 35 and 18 respectively. I find it helpful to look at what these functions actually output in the interactive prompt.

```
>>> print (range(1, 18))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
>>> print (range(1, 35))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
```

Range is nothing other than a list (python 2) or lazy sequence (python 3) from n to n-1 inclusive. Hope this helps.

Comment: You seem to be on Python 2. `range` returns a dedicated lazy sequence type rather than a list on Python 3. (The endpoint handling remains the same, though.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ah sorry my bad, i still use python2.7 even after the EOL because that's what we use at work. you are right about python3 though

Comment: Understood. Thank you for explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

`range(start, end)` does not include `end`. So `range(1,18)` includes the numbers 1 to 17.

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp).

I assume the second for loop in your second example checks values from a list or array. Or even lines in a file. Those start counting at 0.
So the 18th element in the list/file has index 17. Thus you still get it checked.

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
for i in range(0,18):
    print(f"{i}: {a[i]}")
```

Will output:

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4
4: 5
5: 6
6: 7
7: 8
8: 9
9: 10
10: 11
11: 12
12: 13
13: 14
14: 15
15: 16
16: 17
17: 18
```

Comment: Okay understood. Thanks a ton